# Enable bitcode in tvOS framework in Xcode 9.1

Tags: xcode, tvos, bitcode

I'm developing a framework for tvOS in Xcode 9.1. This framework includes a static library (which I compiled and is bitcode enabled).

The problem is that the framework isn't bitcode enabled. I'm using otool to check whether it is bitcode enable or not:

```
tool -l blabla.Framework/myFramwork | grep __LLVM
```

and I get nothing (which means bitcode disabled)

In the build setting in Xcode the option "bitcode enable" doesn't exists.

As I understand bitcode is mandatory for tvOS and the default settings should be YES but somehow it doesn't happened.

What am I missing? What do I need to add?

Answer (score 0):

I don't recall there being an option to turn bitcode ON/OFF for tvOS targets in Xcode from the very beginning. May be in the very initial betas, but that option does not exist for tvOS AFAIK, and builds are bitcode enabled by default, as long as you build for the device. Builds for simulators will not be bitcode enabled.